# Enable cron/crontab overlapping

Tags: linux, bash, cron

We have strange behavior: our cron don't overlap tasks. Its managed by supervisord. On the next example, we have 4 simple tasks, but one task takes more than 1 minute:

`/etc/crontab`:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin

* * * * *  echo "[task1] $(date +\%H:\%M:\%S)" >> /tmp/cron.log
* * * * *  echo "[task2] $(date +\%H:\%M:\%S)" >> /tmp/cron.log  && sleep 90
* * * * *  echo "[task3] $(date +\%H:\%M:\%S)" >> /tmp/cron.log
* * * * *  echo "---" >> /tmp/cron.log
```

This is the output:

```
[task1] 14:54:00
[task2] 14:54:00
[task3] 14:54:00
---
[task1] 14:55:00
[task3] 14:55:00
---
[task1] 14:56:00
[task2] 14:56:00
[task3] 14:56:00
---
[task1] 14:57:00
[task3] 14:57:00
---
```

`supervisord.conf`:

```
[program:crond]
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=/app/docker-entrypoints/cronjobs.sh
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/app/storage/logs/cronjobs.log
stderr_logfile=/app/storage/logs/errors.log
stopwaitsecs=360
```

Our `cronjobs.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
exec crond -f
```

Any idea about how can I "enable" overlapping?

Comment: On my Ubuntu's default crond, I have no problem in overlapping.

Comment: Also cannot reproduce. Does this problem also occur when you use normal crontabs (via `crontab -e`)?